# Why could merge sort compare two items twice?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I'm trying to sort an arraylist using 'Collections.sort'.

this is the code I wrote..

```
ArrayList<Student> arl = new ArrayList<>();
    arl.add(new Student(1, "tom", 26));
    arl.add(new Student(2, "brown", 22));
    arl.add(new Student(3, "kate", 24));
    arl.add(new Student(4, "brad", 23));
    System.out.println(arl);
    for(Student v : arl) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
    Collections.sort(arl, new Comparator<Student>(){
        int count = 1;

        public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
            System.out.println("**compare "+count++ +" time***");
            System.out.println("s1: "+s1.getName() + "(id: " + s1.getId()+")");
            System.out.println("s2: "+s2.getName() + "(id: " + s2.getId()+")");
            return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
        }
    });
```

I get a sorted list but what I'm curious about is why Java compare student id 3 with student id 2 twice? I'm not used to the definition of Mergesort but is this because Java is sorting by algorhythm called Mergesort?

```
**compare 1 time***
s1: brown(id: 2)
s2: tom(id: 1)
**compare 2 time***
s1: kate(id: 3)
s2: brown(id: 2)
**compare 3 time***
s1: kate(id: 3)
s2: tom(id: 1)
**compare 4 time***
s1: kate(id: 3)
s2: brown(id: 2)
**compare 5 time***
s1: brad(id: 4)
s2: kate(id: 3)
**compare 6 time***
s1: brad(id: 4)
s2: brown(id: 2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Collections.sort call Comparator twice with the same arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136236/why-does-collections-sort-call-comparator-twice-with-the-same-arguments)

Comment: @Jakub Balinski Thank you! I should've checked first if someone already asked this sort of question....  Can I ask you one more question? On the first comparison, why s1.getName gets the value of 'brown' istead of 'tom'. It compares student id 1 with student id 2 eventually, but it doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: How much details are necessary? The time complexity of `O(n × log(n))` does already imply that there can be more operations (comparisons) than elements. There is no sorting algorithm that can avoid this for arbitrary input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said before, the main question you asked was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136236/why-does-collections-sort-call-comparator-twice-with-the-same-arguments).

**The question you asked in comment**:

> On the first comparison, why s1.getName gets the value of 'brown' istead of 'tom'. It compares student id 1 with student id 2 eventually, but it doesn't make sense to me...

It's directly related to `Collections.sort` implementation, which you can find [here (OpenJDK 8)](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java#l318). In the first sorting phase, `countRunAndMakeAscending` function is called and we can find in its definition the following line:

```
if (c.compare(a[runHi++], a[lo]) < 0) { // Descending
   ...
```

This is the very first time the comparator you passed is utilized, and it happened that the first argument passed to its `compare` method is the element with higher index (`a[runHi++]`) − and this is the reason it's being printed first.

In the link I've pasted above you can read full implementation of this method.
More on the whole `Collections.sort` algorithm has been already told in answers to the question in the first link, so go check this out if you need a further explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer really helped me to understand the logic!